# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string'

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Hello I have this problem where I have this classes:

```
    class numberOne 
    {
      public long ID {get; set;}
      public string Name {get; set;}
      public string Names {get; set;}
    }
    class numberTwo
    {
     public long[] ID {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
    }
```

they will be list after.

So lets say that the data of those lists are like this

```
   List<numberOne> numberOne = new List<numberOne>();
             numberOne.Add(new numberOne() { ID = 1234 });
             numberOne.Add(new numberOne() { ID = 1334 });
             numberOne.Add(new numberOne() { ID = 1434 });
             numberOne.Add(new numberOne() { ID = 1568 });
    List<numberTwo> numberTwo = new List<numberTwo>();
             numberTwo.Add(new numberTwo() { ID[] = 1234,1334 Name = "sam" });         
             numberTwo.Add(new numberTwo() { ID[] = 1434, Name = "paul" });
             numberTwo.Add(new numberTwo() { ID[] = 1434, Name = "john" });
             numberTwo.Add(new numberTwo() { ID[] = 1568, Name = "john" });
```

I need that the the data can be show like this:

```
ID  | Name | Names
1234|sam   |sam
1334|sam   |sam
1434|paul  |paul, john
1434|john  |paul, john
1568|john  |john
```

So far I have this of code:

```
foreach(var items in numberOne.ToList())
         {
items.Name = numberTwo.Where(a => a.ID.Any(b => b == items.ID)).Select(a => a.Name).Distinct();
items.Names = string.Join(",", numberTwo.Where(a => a.ID.Any(b => b == items.ID)).Select(a => a.Name).Distinct);
```

in this line "`items.Name = numberTwo.Where(a => a.ID.Any(b => b == items.ID)).Select(a => a.Name).Distinct();` " is where I receive the error CS0029

Comment: Some of us don't know by heart what error CS0029 is. Show the entire error message including the types.

Comment: In C#, types are very important. What is the return type of your `Distinct` method call? What is the type of `items.Name`? What did you intend to assign to `items.Name`?

Answer (score 0):

`Name` is a `string` and you pass an `IEnumerable<string>` to a `string`.

you should change your code to this:

```
foreach (var items in numberOne.ToList())
{
    items.Name = string.Join(",", numberTwo.Where(a => a.ID.Any(b => b == items.ID)).Select(a => a.Name).Distinct());
    items.Names = string.Join(",", numberTwo.Where(a => a.ID.Any(b => b == items.ID)).Select(a => a.Name).Distinct());
}
```

Finally your code should be like this:

```
List<numberOne> numberOne = new List<numberOne>();
numberOne.Add(new numberOne() { ID = 1234 });
numberOne.Add(new numberOne() { ID = 1334 });
numberOne.Add(new numberOne() { ID = 1434 });
numberOne.Add(new numberOne() { ID = 1568 });
List<numberTwo> numberTwo = new List<numberTwo>();
numberTwo.Add(new numberTwo() { ID = new long[] { 1234, 1334 }, Name = "sam" });
numberTwo.Add(new numberTwo() { ID = new long[] { 1434 }, Name = "paul" });
numberTwo.Add(new numberTwo() { ID = new long[] { 1434 }, Name = "john" });
numberTwo.Add(new numberTwo() { ID = new long[] { 1568 }, Name = "john" });
foreach (var items in numberOne.ToList())
{
    items.Name = string.Join(",", numberTwo.Where(a => a.ID.Any(b => b == items.ID)).Select(a => a.Name));
    items.Names = string.Join(",", numberTwo.Where(a => a.ID.Any(b => b == items.ID)).Select(a => a.Name));
    Console.Write(items.ID + "\t");
    Console.Write(items.Name + "\t");
    Console.WriteLine(items.Names);
}
```

Result:

```
1234    sam     sam
1334    sam     sam
1434    paul,john       paul,john
1568    john    john
```

Comment: Strictly speaking (and I prefer being strict when discussing programming) the attempt is to _assign_ an `IEnumerable<string>` to a `string` variable.

Comment: @NetMage Thank you. I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    foreach (var items in numberOne.ToList())
    {
        items.Name = numberTwo.Where(a => a.ID.Any(b => b == items.ID)).Select(a => a.Name)
.Distinct().FirstOrDefault();
        items.Names = string.Join(",", numberTwo.Select(a => a.Name).Distinct().ToList());
    }
```

after fixing numberTwo init

```
List<numberTwo> numberTwo = new List<numberTwo>();

    numberTwo.Add(new numberTwo() { ID = new long[] { 1234 }, Name = "sam" });
    numberTwo.Add(new numberTwo() { ID = new long[] { 1334 }, Name = "paul" });
    numberTwo.Add(new numberTwo() { ID = new long[] { 1434 }, Name = "john" });
    numberTwo.Add(new numberTwo() { ID = new long[] { 1568 }, Name = "john" });
```